# Get next page with feedburner

Tags: xml, rss, web, feedburner

Alright, so I'm trying to get the next feed page from a Feedburner RSS feed.

I know with a standard wordpress feed you can do something like:

www.mysite.com/?feed=llama&paged2

to get the second page, but how does one do this with a feedburner powered feed?

i.e,

www.mysite.com/feed/ ?

Having a hard time finding anything on Google about working with feedburner URLs, and unfortunately the site I'm working with is totally masking its Wordpress feed with feedburners instead, so I need to work with it.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this... Im having the same problem with feedburner based XML source data.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page for Feedburner cites a source saying that the API is deprecated.  I notice that the RSS [specification](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#optionalChannelElements) does not have any elements to indicate a next page.  I could not find any in the Atom [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#page-6) either.  I take this to mean that "pagination" is not widely supported, but that's an inference on my part.